# How do I print a SET command in a Visual Studio 2008 build?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, variables, environment

I want to see all of the current environment variables during a build. I'd like to do this in the pre or post-build steps if possible because I don't want to edit the Targets file.  This could print to the Output window or to a file.  I've tried a number of different ways without success. I'm using Visual Studio 2008.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you just keyin set in the Post Build event, it displays the environment variables in the output window.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I was trying too hard, and wrapping the set in %, etc.